# How do I disable displaying the current directory size in SSH?

Tags: command-line, ssh

I have never seen this before. When I ssh into my server I see the current directory size (circled in yellow). When navigating, this adds a lot of overhead as it calculates the folder size every time I change directories.

Is there any way to remove that feature?

[image: Screen shot here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That computation is done in your `bash` "Prompt" (see `man bash`). Edit your `~/.bashrc` and look for where the `PS1` value is defined.

Comment: [`echo $PS1`](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html) might be a handy way to check the value of `PS1` quickly without needing to open `~/.bashrc` first.

Comment: Awesome thank you so much! Found the line and removed it!